# create correlation matrix in r with logical and factoral values

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have data set with factoral, logical and numerical values and I was wondering if I can create a correlation matrix with this:

```
df
Country  Year  Log1   Num1  Log2 ....
A        1995  TRUE   0.5   FALSE
A        1996  FALSE  1.5   FALSE
B        1999  FALSE  3.7   TRUE
C        1999  TRUE   -1.5  TRUE
...
```

while Country (and Year?) is a factoral value, LOG1 & LOG2 are logical values and Num1 is numerical
Is there a way to calculate correlation factors for all values? Is it necessary to assign a number to the factoral values (e.g. Country A = 1, B=2 etc)? And would I have to do this by hand or is there a nice package to do so?
In the ende I would like to receive a correlation table like:

```
              Country      Year    LOG1   Num1   LOG2
Country     1.00000000 0.03892847    NA    NA     NA
Year        0.03892847 1.00000000    NA    NA     NA
LOG1                NA         NA     1    NA     NA
NUM1                NA         NA    NA     1     NA
LOG2                NA         NA    NA    NA      1
```

Of course without the NA and with the right values.
Any idea?
I know that the standard way is 
`correlation <- cor(df)`
or even `correlation <- cor(df[sapply(df,is.numeric)], use='everything')`

THANK YOU!

Comment: You could have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polycor/  `polycor::hetcor` computes a heterogenous correlation matrix, consisting of Pearson product-moment correlations between numeric variables, polyserial correlations between numeric and ordinal variables, and poly-choric correlations between ordinal variables, if that is what you are looking for,

Comment: Hi @user12728748 thank you for the tip! as I understand it is only differentiated between numerical and ordinal values in this case? Are binary variables considered numerical? 
in the description of the package it says: WarningBe careful with character variables (as opposed to factors), the values of which are ordered alphabet-ically. Thus, e.g., the values"disagree","neutral","agree"are ordered"agree","disagree","neutral". So for this case it would make sense to categorize some of the varibles as numeric beforehand right?

Comment: Either that, or turn character values into factors yourself, using factor ordering of your choice. E.g. `factor(c("disagree", "neutral", "agree"), levels(factor(c("disagree", "neutral", "agree")))[c(1, 3, 2)])` (in this simple case `factor(c("disagree", "neutral", "agree"), unique(c("disagree", "neutral", "agree")))` would work, too).

Comment: @user12728748 do you know why the following error could occur?
`Error in if (!chkcorr(corr)) stop(sQuote("corr"), " is not a correlation matrix") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`